# Lazy sizes does not show video

Tags: iframe, lazy-loading

I am using lazy sizes for the lazy load of my youtube videos. On every page the lazy load does work, but not on these two, more precisely, the whole video just disappears/is not displayed. The two pages are in the same folder as all other pages, which do work. The link to lazysizes.js is there `<script src="lazysizes.min.js" async></script>`

Here is the iframe on one of the working pages with the video being displayed:

`<iframe width="640" height="360" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx?rel=0" importance="low" loading="lazy" frameborder="0" class="lazyload" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

and here the iframe that just won't work/does not display the video - it's identical:

`<iframe width="640" height="360" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3FOZ2CTaaWk?rel=0" importance="low" loading="lazy" class="lazyload" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I know this just doesn't make sense, but my hope is that one of you stumbled upon the same problem. I have tried copying and pasting (swapped them, so it is not really the iframe code) and changing it, reloading the js etc. but nothing helps. The iframe is identical with the other pages. I have no idea how to find out what's missing here.

Comment: There's several differences between the two, you should try making the one that isn't working identical to the one that is. `src` -> `data-src`, `allow` content, ect. This is virtually impossible for answerers to debug.

Comment: @robinsax thank you, yes, I just did and swapped them. I just cannot get my head wrapped around it, it is ridiculous. What could interfere with it?

Comment: Like i said, it's pretty hard to debug without access to the environment. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid, the console revealed it: the lazysizes.min.js was loaded into the directory of this particular URL. Since this URL (and its /.../ directory) is artificially created the `lazysizes.min.js` could not be found in that directory (though on the FTP server the js file is in the same directory as the source php file that loads it) it could not be loaded. 
A simple line of extra code that includes the `lazysizes.min.js` above the iframe embedment with an absolute URL to the js file solved the problem!